# Implementing this Full Adder circuit

Tags: digital-logic, adder

For my class, I have to implement the following circuit on a breadboard but I don't really have an idea on how to start. Basically, I have a 4-bit Full Adder and I will input two 4-bit binary numbers into it (A and B). I also have two other inputs (S0 and S1) which decide what kind of operation to carry out.

The operation to be carried out is represented by this table:

[image]

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to start this. My friend told me using a MUX will make this circuit easier, however, we haven't gone over those in class yet. I know I have to use AND and XOR gates and some inverters, but I need someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: *My* internet is full of info on this stuff.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you searched (upper right corner) the other questions here for 4-bit adders?  (I came up with 122 "hits")

Comment: Hint: Implement incrementer, decrementer, adder and subtractor. Then choose one according to control input. Not an efficient, but a straightforward solution.

Comment: What is the datasheet for the adder?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a few hints.  You only need one adder (well two, the second for getting the complement of B)

Obviously, you add A+B with the adder.

A-B can use the same adder, just [complement B first and then add](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~eedwards/compsys/arithmetic/).

A+1 can also use the same adder, just make B = 1.

A-1 can use the same adder, just make B = -1.

Your friend is right, you can use a 4x1 mux where the inputs are the four operands above (B, complement of B, 1 and -1) and the output of the mux is one of the two inputs to the adder, the other being A.  The two lines S0 and S1 select one of the four inputs of the mux.